# Maven - Can't Execute JAR

Tags: java, maven, jar, manifest

After building a sample mvn project, I added my `org.restlet` dependencies & Java code.

Then, I successfully built my JAR via `mvn install`. Finally, I ran into an error when trying to run the JAR.

```
vagrant$ java -jar target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: It's above - `Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: instead of executing "java -jar", can you place your jar in classpath and try to run something like "java MainClass"

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to set the main class in the manifest using the `maven-jar-plugin`

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.someclass.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Taken from [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=72602).

**EDIT**

If you want to package the resulting jar with dependencies you can use this

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/2071828).

Comment: If my package = `com.mycompany.app` and my main class is `com.mycompany.app.MailServerApplication`, `<mainClass>` = latter?

Comment: Yup, the fully qualified class name of a class that has a `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I have my next issue to resolve: `vagrant$ java -jar target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/restlet/Application

Comment: Looks like you need to set a classpath or [package into a single file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/2071828).

Answer (score 4):

If you dont have a manifest in your jar invoking java -jar will not work.

Use this command if you dont have a manifest:

```
java -cp foo.jar full.package.name.ClassName
```

Comment: Hmm: `vagrant$ java -jar target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.MailServerApplication`
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Check your MANIFEST.MF in your jar

Comment: I think you are thinking of `java -cp foo.jar full.package.name.ClassName`. This answer isn't correct. -1

Comment: @bmorris no no, `java -jar foo.jar full.package.name.ClassName` is the command to execute. Maybe `java -cp` work but I have always used `java -jar`

Comment: Take a look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html) - "If the -jar option is specified, the first non-option argument is the name of a JAR archive containing class and resource files for the application, with the startup class indicated by the Main-Class manifest header."